# Traduction de « jailbait »

Tags: traduction, anglais, argot

En anglais « *jailbait* » veut dire qu'il y a une jeune femme, belle et avec laquelle on aimerait peut-être coucher, mais qui donne l'impression d'être mineure. Elle est effectivement mineure et c'est un appât pour attraper l'homme qui la désire et le mettre en prison à la fin.

Existe-t-il une expression équivalente en français?

Comment: Il y a un film noir policier américain qui porte ce titre : JAIL BAIT (USA 1954) de Edward D. Wood Jr. mais l'intrigue n'a aucun rapport avec ces histoires de filles mineures faisant plus que leur âge bien que l'actrice Dolores Fuller qui joue dedans soit mignonne.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Pas que je sache, non.**

Pour traduire, dépendamment du contexte, j'utiliserais soit « mineure » (en tant qu'adjectif, pour parler de la personne, bref le plus souvent), soit éventuellement « appât » (pour parler du piège). C'est à l'interlocuteur de deviner les conséquences légales sous-entendues.

D'ailleurs, le terme n'a peut-être simplement *pas besoin d'être* en français, si les législations contre le phénomène sont plus souples dans les pays francophones qu'anglophones, ce qui ne me surprendrait aucunement.

Answer (score 14):

Je verrais bien [*pousse-au-crime*](http://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/pousse-au-crime).

Comment: (+1) Je me disais bien qu'il y avait quelque chose... dire qu'on a mis 2 mois à retrouver. Bravo à notre invité !

Comment: Oui, très bonne réponse. Je dirais aussi tout simplement un "appât".

Answer (score 9):

D'après la définition de [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jailbait) c'est en fait le contraire. Si j'essaie de traduire les deux premières lignes:

> *Jailbait*, ou *appât Johnny*, est un mot d'argot qui représente une personne mineure n'ayant pas l'âge légal requis pour s'adonner à des pratiques sexuelles [avec un adulte] mais dont la maturité physique peut la faire passer pour une adulte, ce qui peut la rendre sexuellement attirante auprès de personnes non déviantes plus âgées.

J'y ai ajouté *[avec un adulte]* pour appuyer la connotation illégale du mot *jailbait*.

En français je ne connais pas de mot qui exprime directement ce sens. Par contre on peut dire

> Elle fait plus que son âge (*She looks older*)

sans qu'il y ait pour autant la connotation « appât » ou « piège » comme en anglais. Si l'on veut exprimer le sens de *jailbait* entièrement, il faut préciser les choses au travers d'une phrase, comme par exemple

> Attention, cette fille fait plus que son âge mais elle est mineure. Tu risques d'avoir des problèmes [sous entendu avec la police]  si tu sors avec.

Comment: merci d'avoir mis la vraie définition de cette expression

Answer (score 2):

J’ai rencontré cette expression à deux reprises dans *Of Mice and Men* de John Steinbeck, publié en février 1937, et j’ai été curieux de la traduction française, effectuée par Maurice-Edgar Coindreau et publiée en 1949.

Je dois admettre avoir été un peu déçu, mais comme Steinbeck est un grand romancier, j’ai encore tendance à croire qu’il aura bénificié d’une traduction fidèle aux attentes des lecteurs de l’époque. Elle semble indiquer que la traduction de l’expression n’était pas simple. J’ose supposer qu’un traducteur d’aujourd’hui serait plus audacieux, mais ces exemples montrent comment la chose a été approchée par un traducteur littéraire professionnel (que l’on approuve ou non ses choix est une autre discussion, à laquelle j’apporterais bien quelques remarques, mais que je laisserai ici de côté).

Le premier exemple provient du chapitre 2 :

> “Listen to me, you crazy bastard,” he said fiercely. “Don’t you even take a look at that bitch. I don’t care what she says and what she does. I seen ’em poison before, but I never seen no piece of **jail bait** worse than her. You leave her be.”
>
> — Écoute-moi, bougre de con, dit-il furieux, t’avise pas de regarder cette garce. J’ me fous de ce qu’elle dit ou de ce qu’elle fait. C’est pas la première fois que je vois des poisons comme ça, mais j’ai jamais rien vu de meilleur **pour faire coffrer un type**. Laisse-la tranquille.

Le second nous vient du chapitre 3 :

> George said, “She’s gonna make a mess. They’s gonna be a bad mess about her. She’s a **jail bait** all set on the trigger. That Curley got his work cut out for him. Ranch with a bunch of guys on it ain’t no place for a girl, specially like her.”
>
> George dit :
>   — Ça fera du vilain. Sûr qu’il se passera du vilain autour d’elle. C’est **un piège tout tendu pour ceux qu’ aiment la prison**. Le Curley a son travail tout préparé. Un ranch avec un tas de types, c’est pas un endroit pour une femme, surtout une comme ça.

Bien sûr, on aura remarqué que Steinbeck a utilisé ***jail bait*** et non ***jailbait***, mais je crois que c’est mineur et n’influence ni le sens original, ni la traduction qu’on en a tiré.

Comment: [Larousse](http://larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/jailbait/589960) angl.-fr. en ligne avec une tournure qui ressemble à celles que vous présentez... Merci !